# Image view found nil when unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, null, imageview

I have an image that I download from Parse and load into an image view. When I do so I get the following error (with included print of image to show existence):

```
 <UIImage: 0x13707c950>, {2045, 2588}

 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

It is definitely linked up. I have tried cleaning, restarting Xcode, and deleting the view and image and remaking it. I have a companion project that is similar to this, and uses the same code (in a separate method I convert the PFFile into the image). I also know this method works because at another part in the project I load the image in this exact way.

```
if let image = objectsKeyValues[indexNumber]["image"] {

            print(image)

            sALargeNoteImage.imageView.image = image as? UIImage
            sALargeNoteImage.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what's happening. I have done plenty of reworking in the storyboard, even at one point refactoring. This could suggest that it is related (as I have read on SO) to Xcode getting "confused". Not really sure what I should try next, short of remaking the storyboard its on (that would be a lot of work). I suppose I could remake it and copy paste the code..

Anybody have any ideas? I don't use a simulator, instead I load it onto an iPad. I have tried deleting and reinstalling the app.

The part that gets highlighted from the error is:

```
sALargeNoteImage.imageView.image = image as? UIImage
```

update:

```
 var sALargeNoteImage = SALargeNoteImage()

 class SALargeNoteImage: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sALargeNoteImage = self

}
```

Comment: set a breakpoint and examine your variable to determine which one is nil

Comment: It sounds like `sALargeNoteImage` is nil - try printing it and its `imageView` and `image`.

Comment: printed those and it broke on sALargeNoteImage.imageView

Comment: How are you creating `sALargeNoteImage` ?

Comment: I updated to show the code. I had read that it could be that it doesn't get a chance to make the connection and could be related to me setting the VC as a variable like that. But on the other project I do it exactly like that without a problem. Could be related to this project being bigger. Not sure how I can fix this without not using that, since I use references like that quite a bit.

Comment: Why do you have the assignment of `self` to `sALargeNoteImage` in `viewDidLoad`?  That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one point I was testing out if it would clear the image when I set:

```
 lSLargeNoteImage.imageView = nil
```

vs

```
 lSLargeNoteImage.imageView.image = nil
```

I had left it like that by accident, and the function that does that runs before this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating `sALargeNoteImage` using a simple `init`, it will not be connected to any of the outlets in the storyboard.

You need to use something like

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let sALargeNoteImage=storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("largeNoteViewController") as! SALargeNoteImage
```

in order to instantiate the view controller and link all of the IBOutlets

I would highly recommend that you avoid the use of `var someVariable=SomeType()` if all you are trying to do is suppress the error from the compiler that properties must be initialised and you intend to initialise the property properly later.  It is much better to use `var someVariable:SomeType!` as this will throw an exception if you forget to assign a value to the property rather than resulting in obscure bugs where a default value is used.

Comment: Ok, so the name for the storyboard is pretty straightforward (in this case, "StudentAssignments"). For the identifier- should I be putting that "largeNoteViewController" title somewhere on the storyboard?

Comment: Also- (given that this works)- can you share any idea as to why this is needed for this case but doesn't happen for other cases where I use the same init system (literally identical code, even in other places in the project).

Comment: Yes, select the scene in your storyboard and then in the identity inspector on the right set the storyboard id

Comment: I can't say without seeing the other code you have.  Perhaps the code you have shown is a little misleading - I often see Swift programmers say something like `var sALargeNoteImage = SALargeNoteImage()` when what they really mean is `var sALargeNoteImage : SALargeNoteImage!` - i.e. They want to assign the variable later but don't want the compiler to complain about the variable not being initialised.  In the first case you potentially have an issue with the variable not being initialised correctly.  With the second form you get a clear runtime exception if you try and access the nil variable

Comment: broke in the same spot as before

Comment: I don't think you are showing the right code in your question.  In which class is the first block of code you have shown - the one that throws the exception?  How does that code get the reference to the `sALargeNoteImage` view controller?

Comment: the original code I posted occurred in a VC called SANoteAbstraction . Just to check- the code you shared with me, it should be replacing var sALargeNoteImage = SALargeNoteImage() right ?

Comment: No.  That line should read `var sALargeNoteImage : SALargeNoteImage!` Where do you assign another value to that property?  My guess is that you aren't and so you end up referencing the 'empty' view controller instance.  Also why do you assign `self` to a property in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I set it equal to self in viewDidLoad of that ViewController. I basically use this so my VC can communicate with each other. edit- didn't see the other half of your question. eyes getting blurry from spending so much time on what shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: But that makes no sense.  If `a`=your view controller instance and `a` sets its property `b=self` then saying `a.b` is the same as saying `a`.  How does `sALargeNoteImage` get set in your `SANoteAbstraction` class?

Comment: Just to add my 2 cents, you only get that error when your're force unwrapping an Optional, and the only place where this is done in the code you've shown is `sALargeNoteImage.imageView`. Therefore it's probably the cause, and the most likely candidate is that the imageView is not hooked up to the code. You could confirm with `print(sALargeNoteImage.imageView)`.

Comment: No, I suspect that it is actually that an instance of the view controller instantiated from a storyboard has never been assigned to that property, so instead it references the empty instance created by `var sALargeNoteImage = SALargeNoteImage()` which is why that is bad habit to get into.  If you are going to initialise a variable later, use `:Type!` not `=Type()` because the former will throw an exception if you forget to initialise it while the latter will give less obvious issues such as the one here

Comment: You seem to be correct, setting it = to self in viewDidLoad may be redundant. It's something I saw when researching on SO when I first started and somehow I kept that convention w.o testing to see if it was necessary. However, changing that didn't seem to affect the issue that I have now (same error). Perhaps I can send you the project. As I was saying, I use this exact same code and structure in other places in the project and in another project and I doesn't cause an issue, so I think its something wrong with the storyboard.

Comment: You can either add your code to a github gist or add a link to a zip file and I will have a quick look

Comment: When I mouse over the link in the VC, it highlights the image, confirming that it is linked. And I have deleted and recreated it several times. I'm thinking- 1) something wrong with storyboard or 2) VC getting initialized in a way that its not creating link. I will heed your advice regarding the convention, Paul, but I can't see how its the culprit if identical code in other spots don't have the issue.

Comment: Will send it over. Thanks. Going to take a bit of time to zip it up.

Comment: My guess is that if you change the declaration of `sALargeNoteImage` to `var sALargeNoteImage : SALargeNoteImage!` in the class that is crashing you will still get a crash but it will be because `sALargeNoteImage` itself is nil.

Comment: At one point I was testing out if it would clear the image when I set it to         lSLargeNoteImage.imageView = nil vs         lSLargeNoteImage.imageView.image = nil . I had left it like that by accident, and the function that does that runs before this.

Comment: Whats the best convention to leave that as an answer? I feel like that could be useful to someone (i.e. someone setting the imageView to nil in another place in their code).

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question

Comment: Thanks for your time BTW. I will heed your advice regarding how to declare the VC.